# Is it true that an estimator will always asymptotically be consistent if it is biased in finite samples?

Tags: econometrics, bias, consistency

Is it true that an estimator will always asymptotically be consistent if it is biased in finite samples?
I feel like it is true but not sure exactly how to prove that...

Comment: Suppose this were so.  Then take any such estimator and add some arbitrary constant to it so that it remains biased in finite samples: by construction it is *not* asymptotically consistent.

Comment: @whuber, this should be an answer, and it would arguably be the best among the ones posted.

Comment: @RichardHardy Not the whole story. Asymptotic consistency is useless without evidence of sufficient convergence.

Comment: @Carl, this is beyond the OP's question. What do you mean by *sufficient convergence*?

Comment: @RichardHardy Sufficient for confidence in the results, as in confidence intervals, without which one is guessing as to validity. I took it upon myself to answer in the useful context, and not just lay down alms on the altar of asymptotic consistency. So, shoot me.

Comment: @RichardHardy Sometimes reducing variance is more important than asymptotic consistency, as in Tikhonov regularization, so, a more complete answer is arguably more important than a yes/no one. Indeed the answer to the OP question is a simple "NO" so how can you justify any answer longer than that? And, a 'No" answer is not even long enough for a comment on this site. The devil is in the details, and it is a matter of taste as to how much of the issue one characterizes. Your preference on this is more narrow than mine, congrats.

Comment: A similar question is discussed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator#Bias_versus_consistency).

Comment: *"I feel like it is true"* I wonder about the intuition behind this.

Answer (score 26):

Consider the estimator $\hat{\theta} = 3$.  If this estimator is estimating a parameter that is not equal to three then it is biased in all finite samples.  Is this estimator asymptotically consistent?

Comment: +1 Sometimes we forget that such simple possibilities exist. It is good to be reminded of that.

Answer (score 6):

Next to the simple and effective example of Ben, here is a more applied and specific one: Imagine you try to estimate a causal effect, but your regression model to estimate this causal parameter is misspecified (often called "omitted variable bias").

A well-known example deals with returns to schooling, i.e., how much more you earn *due to* (i.e., in the sense of a causal effect of sitting in class, taking courses) additional schooling. If you simply regress earnings on schooling the regression is likely misspecified, because people (after compulsory schooling ends) *choose* how much schooling they want. Now, more motivated and able students will, as a tendency, find the idea of going to school for longer less daunting than other students. Now, such able and motivated persons will however also be likely to be good at the workplace due to these characteristics, irrespective of how much schooling they have. Hence, they will likely earn more.

Hence, you would need to control for things like ability/motivation - which  may not be easy in practice - in your regression (and likely other things, too).

Just collecting more data on your simple regression of earnings on schooling will, in turn, not save you from this problem, so both biased and inconsistent estimation. For both small and large datasets, the simple regression, as a tendency, compares earnings of students who are both able *and* have higher schooling to earnings of students who are less able *and* have less schooling. Assigning the entire difference in earnings to schooling hence will overstate the causal effect of schooling.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in some circumstances, no in others. For example, if a bias results from a self-inconsistent assumption, then no. Examples of this latter include [omitted variable bias](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/6-1-omitted-variable-bias.html) and AIC in the case of censored data, which violates the maximum likelihood assumption. Examples of when it pertains would be AIC in the case of complete support (i.e., without censoring such that the maximum likelihood assumption pertains), and ordinary least squares for equidistant independent axis data. In still others, for example, variance is generally unbiased, but standard deviation is not, see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/249688/99274). Standard deviation would still be asymptotically correct because the [small number bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) would reduce to zero for $n\to\infty$. Nevertheless, one should not rely on just any asymptotic convergence, if a rather better estimator is available, and see how this was done in this [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/249688/99274).  Briefly, if you small number correct standard deviations from a large number of 2 sample SD's and then average them, you will obtain a more variable estimate than if you root mean square combine all the variances and then use a much lesser small number correction for the total number of trials. Some people are surprised at how [ineffectual](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/371068/99274)  AIC can be for small samples. Thus, how fast asymptotic convergence occurs can be critical to interpretation of statistical results, and sometimes, for example for AIC, when we do not have measures that inform us of how precise or accurate statistical results are, it can be problematic.

Thus, the question of whether or not a procedure is asymptotically convergent is not by itself a sufficient criterion of validity of statistical results. We also need confidence intervals for those results.

Comment: Did you mean "censored" rather than "censured"?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Indeed. Nice pickup. I changed the spelling.

Comment: That is an interesting slip --- censured data sounds fascinating!

Comment: @Ben Ha, ha. Glad I could tickle your funny-bone. At least someone, you, or should I call you "them" has a sense of humor on this depressing site.

Comment: Why "them".  Are you making fun of my multiple personality disorder?  ; )

Comment: @Ben You are a joy, and put lightness in my heart. No, I was making fun of the web site, and "their" misplaced sense of propriety.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true that an estimator will always asymptotically be consistent
> if it is biased in finite samples?

The correct reply is trivial and it is NO, as pointed out above.

However your question immediately suggest a more interesting one:

*Is it true that an estimator will always asymptotically be consistent if it is **unbiased** in finite samples?*

The reply is: yes, if its variance going to zero when sample size diverge.

I add this part here because I suppose can be interesting for some readers.

Comment: What if the variance is decreasing but converges to a positive number rather than zero?

Comment: I Richard! In my experience I never encounter situation like this. However I suppose that no kind of consistency is achieved if the estimator variance have a lower bound greater that zero.

Comment: I think so too. Consider editing this into your answer.

Comment: ok, I made the answer it more precise.

Comment: Though what if the variance is infite but, say, the mean absolute deviation goes to zero?

Comment: Estimators with infinite variance is an advanced topic. I think that for address this point, first of all, we should be agree on all details about the meaning of consistency. Here I just wanted to give an easy intuition to the readers.

Comment: Sure, and that is great. I just think the devil is in the details, so better get them right.